# MySQL MariaDB Average Cost Calculatiton based on FIFO Method (First In - First Out)

Tags: mariadb, mysql-5.7

I have the following table of transactions - print screen simplified (positive Qty is a buy, while negative Qty is a sell):

[image]

Based on the above data, I would like to calculate average buying price for each record, based on FIFO method. Expected output:

[image]

I have managed to do most of it, but I am having problem getting correct price for sold items based on FIFO method (marked yellow in the table above). I am using the following query:

```
SET @inventory_qty:=0;
SET @inventory_value:=0;

SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(TransactioinDate, "%Y-%m-%d") AS TransDate,
    CoinID,
    @trans_qty:= ( CASE TransactioinType WHEN 1 THEN TransactioinQty WHEN 2 THEN TransactioinQty * (-1) END ) AS Qty,
    TransactioinPrice AS Price,
    @trans_val:= ( @trans_qty * TransactioinPrice ) AS TransValue,
    @inventory_qty:= ( @inventory_qty + @trans_qty ) AS InventoryQty,
    @inventory_value:= ( @inventory_value + @trans_val ) AS InventoryValue,
    @avgbuyprice_fifo:= ( @inventory_value / @inventory_qty ) AS AvgBuyPrice_FIFO
FROM transactions
ORDER BY TransactioinDate;
```

My current output of the above query is the following:

[image]

As you can see, I don't know how to get the Price by FIFO method for sold items. Once this is solved and null values are replaced, all other columns will be solved as well, as there are only simple calculations.

Attaching CREATE TABLE + DATA INSERTS here:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `transactions`
--

CREATE TABLE `transactions` (
  `TransactioinID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `PortfolioID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `WalletID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CoinID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VsCoinID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VsCurrencyID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TransactioinType` int(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '1 = Buy, 2 = Sell, 3 = Transfer IN, 4 = Transfer OUT',
  `TransactioinPrice` double DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Per coin, if you multiply this value by quantity, you get total trade value',
  `TransactioinQty` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `TransactioinDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `TransactioinFees` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `TransactioinNote` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `TransactionStatus` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`TransactioinID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;


--
-- Dumping data for table `transactions`
--

INSERT INTO `transactions` VALUES (1,2,1,1368,NULL,26,1,12.5,1,'2019-01-01 00:00:00',0,NULL,1),(2,2,1,1368,NULL,26,1,10.99,3,'2019-01-02 00:00:00',0,NULL,1),(3,2,1,1368,NULL,26,2,NULL,1,'2019-01-04 00:00:00',0,NULL,1),(4,2,1,1368,NULL,26,2,NULL,1,'2019-01-05 00:00:00',0,NULL,1),(5,2,1,1368,NULL,26,1,12,2,'2019-01-09 00:00:00',0,NULL,1);
```

Comment: Provide sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts, not as pictures. PS. On MySQL 5.7 you must use iterative stored procedure - this version does not support recursive CTEs. Variables cannot help - buyed and celled rows are not dependent, hence you need in 2 table copies for to perform your task, but the order of variables processing in multiple-table query is unpredictable.

Comment: How do you compute 11.3675 from 10.99?  I can't help you without understanding the formulas.

Comment: MySQL 8.0 and MariaDB 10.2 support CTEs; what version are you running?

Comment: There are actually only 2 simple formulas:

TransValue = Qty * Price; AvgBuyPrice_FIFO = InventoryValue / InventoryQty;

All other columns are simply running totals.

Comment: Please don't post results as screen shots. The community can't use the data in screen shots to replicate data. Instead consider reading the meta article **[New Feature: Table Support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support)** on how to create attractive output. Thanks.